# How to execute functions of multiple classes dynamically from a package which contains multiple java source files?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a java application that will be running for long periods of time. In this java application there will be a package where multiple number of java files will be there. The name of the classes will be same to the name of the java files. And all the classes will contain 2-3 functions(fixed name of functions for each class) but their definition will be changed from one java file to another.

So how can I do this? One solution which I have already have is using java reflection. But I don't want to implement it using java reflection. I do have a constraint regarding this,in my project.

Kindly help me out. Provide your valuable comment.

Comment: For example : classA contains execute1() and execute2() these two methods.classB contains execute1() and execute2() these two methods. Now I want to invoke these two functions from these two classes. How can I do that thing without using java reflection ?

Comment: That is what java reflection is for.  Can you elaborate on why you can't use reflection?  Another possibility would be to use your java program to kick off a new java process that uses that code.  So basically a java program executing the JVM.

Comment: I can't tell u the exact possible reason about not using the java reflection. But I have been asked not use it. So it's better I need to find another solution. So can u elaborate a little more about ur second approach? Provide me some coding or links .. Thanks 4 ur response ..

Comment: @FrobberOfBits .. If I initiate a separate java process in that case I need to call the methods manually . How it will be possible for me two invoke them dynamically ?

Comment: Harry - you would design your other methods to have a main method.  But seriously, you need to double check why you can't use reflection.  What you're asking about is what reflection is for!!!  This is like saying that you're thirsty, but you're not allowed to have any fluid, and you can't specify why??!?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits - I can understand ur point. But really speaking, if u have any other solution to do this, then u can share with me ..

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what dynamic level you need,
but you can use interface, and other classes implements it

```
Interface MainClass{
    public void method1(int param1);
    public void method2(String param1);
    public void method3();
}

Class Sub1 implements MainClass{

    public void method1(int param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }
    public void method2(String param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }

    public void method3(){
    //blah blah blah
    }

}

Class Sub2 implements MainClass{

    public void method1(int param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }
    public void method2(String param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }

    public void method3(){
    //blah blah blah
    }
}

Class SubN implements MainClass{

    public void method1(int param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }
    public void method2(String param1){
    //blah blah blah
    }

    public void method3(){
    //blah blah blah
    }
}

Class Starter{

    private Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
    private Sub2 s2 = new Sub1();
    private Sub3 sn = new Sub1();


    s1.method1(12);
    s2.method2("OK");
    //blah blah blah
}
```

#####EDIT / Update ------------------------------------------------

this is what i mean by starter-target sol,
the target is the 50 or 100 class you want to run
and the starter is the class that will instantiate all of them and call the methods inside

the idea here, is that, the starter class is auto generated
auto compiled, and then as a normal class, instantiated and used.

find sample full sol:

```
class Generator{
    public boolean generateStarter(String classesPath, String writePath){
        File classes = new File(classesPath);
        String allClasses[] = classes.list();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("Class Starter {\n");
        str.append("public void go(){\n");

        String tmpVarName = "";
        for(int a=0;a<allClasses.length;a++){
            //XXX var1 = new XXX();
            tmpVarName = generateVariableName();
            str.append(getClassName(allClasses[a]) + " " + tmpVarName + " = new " + getClassName(allClasses[a]) + "();\n");
            str.append(tmpVarName + ".method1();\n");//as method names are known and fixed...
            str.append(tmpVarName + ".method2();\n");//as method names are known and fixed...

            str.append(tmpVarName + ".methodN();\n\n");//as method names are known and fixed...
        }//for loop
        str.append("}//go()\n");
        str.append("}//CLASS Starter");

        //save the file to be compiled.
        writeFile(writePath,str.toString());
            return true;
    }//generateStarter()
    private String getClassName(String fileName){
        return fileName.split(".")[0];
    }
    private String generateVariableName(){
        //return a random variable name ex, hja123;
            //or you can pass class name and return className.toLowercase();
    }
    private void writeFile(String path, String data){
        //writes a text file, with data inside...
    }


//output of class generator should be something like this
/*

Class Starter{

    private Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
    private Sub2 s2 = new Sub1();
    private Sub3 sn = new Sub1();


    s1.method1();
    s2.method2();
    //blah blah blah
}
*/
}//CLASS Generator

class Compiler{

    public boolean compile(String javaClassPath){
        getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"c:\\java\\bin\\javac.exe",javaClassPath});
        return true;
    }
}//CLASS  Compiler

class MainStarter{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //c:\\projx\\com\\libs\\ is the path of the 100 or 200 classes (target classes) you want to run.
        //c:\\projx\\Starter.java is the path for the class that will run the 100 class (target classes) [auto generated]
        Generator generator = new Generator("c:\\projx\\com\\libs\\","c:\\projx\\Starter.java");
        if(generator.generateStarter()){
        Compiler compiler = new Compiler();
            if(compiler.compile("c:\\projx\\Starter.java")){
                //the class is no exist and complied, so you can instantiate it and call method go()
                Starter starter = new Starter();
                starter.go();
            }else{//compiled OK
                System.out.println("compile failed!");
            }
        }else{//generated OK
            System.out.println("generate failed!");
        }
    }//main()
}//MainStarter()
```

Comment: you can even make an array of type MainClass, and instantiate each item as different sub-type, and call methods in a for loop or whatever you need

Comment: @Yazan- If I implement an interface, and my all classes override the method, till this it's fine. But I don't want to create the instances of class statically. Sometimes my number of java files can be 50 and next time it can be 100. So number of classes can get  changed. So I can't create the instances in a hard code manner . So any other idea will be really appreciable.

Comment: but these files need to be compiled, right? i mean .class not .java, however, with u can't use reflection i can think of one sol for now, its little crazy, to generate a starter class based on target classes, compile it, then run it, if you interested i can write you some codes. ..
---------------
but why i have that feeling, that you can use 1 class only, not 50 not 100 and pass some params to this class and based on passed params the class will behave ...?!

Comment: Yes,the files need to be compiled. I can't get ur starter class and target class concept or that passing parameter funda. Please can u explain a little bit more , with some code ..It would be helpful.

Comment: about passing params, it depends on the logic you want to do, you can do it yourself by asking a question, what is the differences betweeen the same method in each class, is it a path and and ID for example, so my point you can pass some params in the constructure of the class and based on these params you can handle the cases in each method...

if this is not the case i will write you a sample for the starter-target concept but i need some time :)

Comment: Ok, I can understand ur param passing concept. I will try to implement it. Waiting for ur starter-target concept.

Comment: heads up, i have edited the post above, included the starter-target idea, it might be crazy, i hope this helps you